# How to retrieve the Deleted files in Cpanel...?

Tags: file, cpanel

I need to retrieve the deleted files in Cpanel.,Is any possible to retrieve that means.,pls guide me as soon as possible.,Because i lost my site now....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

I hope this answer hasn't come too late, but it may help someone else anyway...

Yes you probably can get back your files if your cPanel is set up to do regular backups which is the default setting (at least with my web host, Pickaweb).

1. Log in to cPanel.
2. Find Files > Backups
3. Choose the most recent backup where you know your file/folder still existed.
4. Save the file, which will be a .tar.gz (don't let the filename put you off, this is just like a .zip file).
5. Unzip the file (I like to use www.7-zip.org) and then unzip it again... and hopefully there will be your missing files!

Screen shots here: [www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-restore-accidentally-deleted-files-in-cpanel](http://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-restore-accidentally-deleted-files-in-cpanel)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the cpanel you find on most web hosting companies, the normal response will be to restore from a backup you took. I cant log into mine from work (port restrictions) so, Im trying to remember, Im fairly sure there was no undelete to my knowledge.

Try the restore from a backup, or even contact their support. They may do backups you dont know of.

Comment: Unix doesnt do "undelete" chances are your webhosting is on unix, if you didnt backup, chances are no - but as I said contact the support, they would be the ones with the answers

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your hosting company support, any hosting company should have a backup system in place, whether it's cPanel automated backups or a more advanced system such as R1Soft CDP backups.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying backups:

1. from CPANEL
2. open FILE MANAGER and
3. check your trashcan (top right, in this Brazilian install it's "EXIBIR LIXEIRA").

[image: TrashCan]

If this just happened, that's where you'll find your files.